# Leverage browser caching issue on google page speed tool

Tags: .htaccess, caching

i am getting issues for Leverage browser caching for images on Google page speed tool. I have search all web for this issue but not get any solution.
I have tried total cache, wp super cache, zencahe,etc and i have also tried to edit my ht-access file for this and defined expiration for each image type but still i am getting this issue. Can you help me out please.Please tell me what is the cause of this issue so that i am beware next time.I also get this issue when i enable g-zip compression from ht-access file.
Your suggestion will be valuable for me.

Thanks